# ReactJs changed state not show

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Online Demo: **[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-y6xgb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

Using `react` with `semantic-ui`

**Explaination**

I made a component called `Alert` contains `semantic-ui` `modal`, I call this modal on click on a button in a page, this modal contains an `input`, it has two `handler` both seems working, because I debugged with `console.log`, kinda it work in background but not show change, better say `state` that changed not show until I close `modal` and open again.

**Code View:**

When I click on button, call modal by this handler:

```
this.state = {
...
   amount: 50000
}

Increase = (e) => {
    let Html = (<div><Input value={this.state.amount} onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/></div>)
    let obj = {
        size: 'tiny',
        content: Html,
    }

    this.setState({
        alertOpen: true,
        alert: obj
    })
}
```

As you see, it has two handler, `onChange` and `onBlur`; now modal is open, value is `50000` (it set in default state), I want to change input value, but it won't change, not editable, but changed value return in console, now If I close `modal` and open again, it show new value. Same for onblur.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let v = e.target.value;
    console.log(v)
    this.setState({
        amount: v
    })
}

handleBlur = (e) => {
    let v = e.target.value;
    console.log(v)
    if(v < 50000){
        this.setState({
            errorMessagePrice: 'Error message!',
            amount: 50000
        })
    }
}
```

**My opinion:**

I think this happen because I trying to update `state` inside another component (alert), If I right, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your modal content is created once, when you click the button, but it is never updated when the `amount` changes (*because it is being re-rendered from the state*)

The easiest way would be to not store the modal content in state, but generate it when you pass it to the modal.

```
 <Alert
  size={this.state.alert.size}
  content={
    <div>
      <Input
        value={this.state.amount}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      />
    </div>
  }
  open={this.state.alertOpen}
  close={this.goClose}
  actions={this.state.alert.actions}
/>
```

updated codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-fwcfm

---

If you have to *keep* it in the `state` you should make it a function and call it when passing it to the modal (*effectively generating it each time*)

updated codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-nqs95

Comment: Your solution working like a charm, thanks, but If I want go with your first advice, I mean `The easiest way` , How can I generate it when I pass to modal?

Comment: I think re-generating content every time is not a good practice

Comment: Alert content should be dynamically assigned, I guess. It can be an Input element or a select element. Anyway, storing alert content as a component state would be a good option for extensibility. Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can re-generate the alert content every time you render the Waller component, but it is not the best solution from the view of performance. I think the solution is to update the alert content state when handleChange or handleBlur is called. In this way, we can update the alert content only when it needs to be updated.

Please check [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-qqe85)

Comment: We can write this component as a function component using React Hook. In this case, React.useMemo would be used for avoiding un-necessary re-generating.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `Component` is not re rendering to show updated state is because your `input` element is in a function, which React is unable to track.

Move this code

```
<div>
        <Input
          value={this.state.amount}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
      </div>
```

into your render function of `waller` and it will update properly.  Like this:

```
          <Alert
          size={this.state.alert.size}
          content={this.state.alert.content}
          open={this.state.alertOpen}
          close={this.goClose}
          actions={this.state.alert.actions}
        />
        <Input
          value={this.state.amount}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        <Button onClick={this.Increase}>Increase</Button>
```

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I already told you, move your input element into the render function.

Comment: No I can't move input to alert, because alert is global component, content is dynamic

Comment: Don't move it to alert, move it to the render function of waller.  I edited my comment to be more explicit

Comment: oh I see, let me try

Answer (score 0):

This is Correct way to assign Jsx as a variale

```
renderSomeJSX() {
return <Jsx />;
}

render() {
 retrun (
    < />
     {//use the method as a variable be calling it}
     {this.renderSomeJSX()}
 )}}
```

you are Not using a return statement in the input variable.

this is how to SetState from a Child Component using props

```
this.props.stateAction()
```

in Parent Component

```
stateAction = () => {
this.setState({var:value})
}
```

because you said " because I trying to update state inside another component (alert), If I right, how can I fix this?"